# How do you remove dependencies from a library?

Tags: library, neopixel

I'm writing a library for a project i created, but it depends on the Neopixel library from adafruit. I want to remove this dependency and have my library be a stand-alone library.

Is there a way to run a ws2811 chip without the neopixel or similar library?

Comment: Yes. Copy the code from the Neopixel library into yours.

Comment: Why is it important to remove the dependency? Of course there is a way to run the WS2811 chip, but you would have to implement the documented protocol yourself, which has already been done several times by several library authors.

Comment: I understand. but i want to just run the chip - its not running rgb leds.

Answer (score 1):

The [Adafruit Neopixel library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_NeoPixel) is licensed under GPL v3. You can fork a copy of this library into your own code and modify it to suit your own requirements, but if you distribute your code, your compiled project, or a product containing the library or any portion of it, you must ensure you follow the rules of the license by which the library is governed. Those terms of license may include release of the source code if you use any portion of the licensed library in a product. Opinions differ on the exact meaning of GPL v3 with libraries.

You should be able to copy the library into your own codebase and strip out the color-specific routines, put in your own application-specific data-setting routines, but use the same underlying protocol implementation.